# Wordpress background image CSS not working

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image

I'm trying to use background image on wordpress however it isn't working any help would be appreciated.

I have used inline styling for background image as I found other answers on here saying to do this but it still won't work.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left" style =" <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>background-image: url('/img/img/6c0bfc47-d8d3-41f4-9c17-7fca574b5efc.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h1>Windows and Glass</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pretium dui a tortor facilisis, a ornare enim pretium. Duis turpis neque, porta tincidunt vehicula vitae, congue sed elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque lacinia ipsum vulputate, pretium ligula vitae, auctor augue. Ut volutpat ipsum quis ligula cursus, et pulvinar elit sollicitudin. Duis eu interdum libero. Sed dignissim fermentum eros id dapibus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove this `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>`

Comment: I have tried this and it still doesn't work

Comment: Check the output in webdeveloper tools in browser it should be more clear for you what is happening. You should probably move `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` into `url()` (depend on your project's structure)

Comment: Thank you @PiotrKliks you were correct, it is working now.

Comment: Submit an answer @PiotrKliks ;)